# Video and audio icon is missing in the ribbon for the blogs

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I am having issues to upload videos at blog. The Video and audio icon is missing in the ribbon. I think that is topic of permissions. This issue doesn't occur for a farm administrator user. When I create a page, I can upload videos, but not at the blog.

Comment: Can the users see Picture Icon?

Comment: Yes, they can see Picture Icon

Answer (score 1):

Referring your question and comments above i am bit confused.

But if you are saying that you completely don't see the Video and Audio icon in your ribbon make sure that you have Server Publishing Feature On.

If you say that the you can see the icons in ribbon but the are disabled(grayed out), in this case please make sure that, page where you are trying to add this Audio/Video is either a Wiki Page or a Publishing page.

Comment: I cann't see the Video and Audio icon in my ribbon when create a blog. I have Server Publishing Feature On.